# Using a Macro to get excel to check a spreadsheet for a match to a data entry

Tags: excel

I have checked many possible answers but none match it close enough.
Our fixtures inventory is on Excel.
1) I use a scanner to check the tag numbers on inventory items which puts it in another sheet.
2) Currently after I finish a room of furniture I sort the numbers in numeric order than move to the main sheet and copy the tag numbers (already in numeric order) and description and past it into the next column. 
3) I then compare the numbers to see that they match.

I can create a macro to copy and paste the first number row but it won't do the next one.

Also when recording the macro I am coping the tag number from the cell and pasting it in search, when it matches I copy and paste the matched cell (tag number) and next cell to it ( description of item) to my target cell.
But I am not sure the macro is doing the search or just using what I set to copy.

Inventory sheet Column A = room number Column D=inventory tag Column E= description.

**Example of what I want it to do:**
I scan in product code 67-12345. [would be in column D sheet = inventory check}
I want the computer to move to the Inventory sheet
do a search for that tag number
When it gets a match [from column D in sheet = inventory]
copy and paste that cell and the one next to it [column D,E as well as column A (all on the same row) sheet = inventory] into sheet inventory check = [column D (D=D), E (E=E)and(C=A)

note: {info copied from A Inventory sheet into C inventory check sheet}*

Then go to the next row in [column D sheet = inventory check] and if populated continue the process.

I can live with having to run the macro for each line check, it just means running it 40 or 50 times per room.

I hope I have not made this too confusing in trying to explain it completely. Any help would be appreciated. I'm competent in Visual Basic for not overly complicated stuff. Also I use EXCEL 2013

Comment: Are you sure you need a macro? This sounds like a lookup formula would work, no?

Comment: I have no experience with using lookup formula, from what I glanced at in excel help it looks like it will do at least part of what I want. I will look into it more at work tomorrow. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Okay, lookup formula didn't work because it only reads to the right of the target match. With some help we got it to work perfectly with Index.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: What lookup did you use? Ah, I see you found index/match worked. Would you mind posting your answer here for future folks who may have similar questions?

Comment: =INDEX(Inventory!A2:A6435,MATCH(A4,Inventory!D2:D6435,0)) is the formula used to give me the information from column A of the main inventory sheet. =INDEX(Inventory!E2:E6435,MATCH(A4,Inventory!D2:D6435,0)) is used to provide the information from column E. I decided I didn't need to move column D since that was the index match anyway.  When I scan in the tag number it flips to the main sheet and finds the match than pulls out the room number and description to insure I am looking at the correct tag match. If I don't get a match than I know which item to check for error. Works great.

Comment: Sorry, as I looked at what I copied into my reply I realized there was a minor error. I didn't have the cells locked so as I copied and pasted into my inventory check sheet the cell range adjusted as I went down the column. The corrected formula for column A is =INDEX(Inventory!$A$2:$A$6435,MATCH(A4,Inventory!$D$2:$D$6435,0)) the corrected formula for column E is =INDEX(Inventory!$E$2:$E$6435,MATCH(A4,Inventory!$D$2:$D$6435,0))